# Restart Directory / Clear a range of specific lines in a script in the middle of running the code

Tags: python, pandas, enumerate

I'm trying to save dataframes to csv files, but using a sub-directory to allocate it to gives an error, `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Using absolute path works and by running everything, then commenting out the rest of my script (not clearing the variables) then only running the code to save the dataframe, using sub-directories works.
So the path directories that i have used before saving the dataframe (in the same script), somehow affects it.

Here is a very general code of my script

```
check = "Data\\"
def my_function(directory):
    (myfunction)
    return allvars;

directories = [os.path.abspath(x[0]) for x in os.walk(check)]
directories.remove(os.path.abspath(check)) 

list_of_df = []
for i in directories:
    try:
        os.chdir(i)
        x = my_function(i)
        list_of_df .append(x)
    except(ValueError):
        continue

#specific savepath needed otherwise error!
savepath = 'MY_ABSOLUTE_PATH\\'
for a, b in enumerate(list_of_df ):
#    b.to_csv(savepath+dataframe{}.csv'.format(a)) #WORKS
    b.to_csv('Data\\Random\\dataframe{}.csv'.format(a)) #ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

to_csv does create the file if it doesn't exist as you said, but it does not create directories that don't exist. Ensure that the subdirectory you are trying to save your file within has been created first.

I often do something like this in my work:

```
import os

outname = 'name.csv'

outdir = './dir'
if not os.path.exists(outdir):
    os.mkdir(outdir)

fullname = os.path.join(outdir, outname)    

df.to_csv(fullname)
```

This can easily be wrapped up in a function if you need to do this frequently.

Comment: Yes, i was aware of that. Files have already been created before hand

Comment: this creates a file directory "deep" in one of the files that i run my code to initially. I was hoping to to restart to the current working directory of the script

Comment: you mean,restart python script within?

Comment: If so then  "os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)" then it should work.